# Rotate Html Canvas with image and drawing

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

So I have a canvas with a background image that has a user defined dot / coordinate on it.

I want to rotate the entire canvas with the image and the dot to stay in exactly the same place.

How do I do that.

This is what I have

```
      var canvas = document.getElementById("car");
      canvas.width = 364;
      canvas.height = 219;
      canvas.style = "border:1px solid red";
      var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

      const image = "https://i.ibb.co/cYfp8SQ/sedan.jpg";
      let canvasImg = new Image();
      canvasImg.src = image;
      canvasImg.onload = () => {
        canvasContext.drawImage(canvasImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      };

      setTimeout(() => {
        canvasContext.fillStyle = "red";
        canvasContext.beginPath();
        canvasContext.arc(110, 80, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        canvasContext.fill();
      }, 200);
```

I have read a bunch of articles about rotating with translate and rotate, but all of them is with either a drawing, or an image, not both.

Is there a way to rotate this canvas while keeping the coordinate intact?

I made a fiddle to reference
https://jsfiddle.net/heinrichcoetzee/sjcxdv08/2/

What it currently looks like ->
[image]

What I want it to look like ->

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand the question - you want the image to rotate around the dot, with the dot not moving? If yes, then a good approach is to set the canvas's transform-origin to match the dot's position on the canvas. Transform-origin will accept %coordinates, which should make the calculation a bit easier. Check out the MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the CSS:

```
canvas {
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}
```

Or in JS:

```
  const canvas = document.getElementById("car");
  canvas.style.border = "1px solid red";
  canvas.style.transform = "rotateZ(90deg)";
```